# Globally use Google's malloc?

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, tcmalloc

I'd like to experiment with Google's tcmalloc on Linux... I have a huge project here, with hundreds of qmake generated Makefile's... I'd like to find a way to get gcc to globally link against tcmalloc (like it does with libc)... Is this possible? Or will I have to edit every Makefile?

(I'd prefer not to edit all the pro files as there are hundreds of them)

(Also, we've already tried the LD_PRELOAD method and it's not working quite right)...

Comment: Can't you just edit qmake's .pro files?

Comment: Can you give more info about LD_PRELOAD not working correctly?  What exactly are you experiencing when you try to use LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: Well, it looked like only part of the application was using tcmalloc... Vast swaths of it's allocs were NOT going to tcmalloc... I tried to use ltrace to verify this but ltrace crashed fairly quickly (BTW, ltrace showed only calls into qt, and tcmalloc also only generated a report showing qt code... however, a lot more things are calling malloc in this app)...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553435/tcmalloc-how-can-i-get-my-malloc-calls-overridden-when-compiling-statically

Comment: -nostdlibs is interesting, but I would need some way to globally do this or else I'm back to editing hundreds of makefiles or .pro files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do your makefiles access the compiler (**gcc/g++/cc/c++**)?

If it's just by name (**g++**), and not by explicit path (**/usr/bin/g++**), you can simply create a replacement g++ in whatever directory you prefer, and prepend that directory to your path.

E.g.:  Create a    **~/mytmpgccdir/g++**     file:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
exec /usr/bin/g++ -Lfoo -lfoo $*:q
```

Adding whatever extras (**-Lfoo -lfoo**) you like, either before or after the other arguments (**$*:q**).

Then pre-pend it to your path and make normally.

```
#tcsh version
% set path = ( ~/mytmpgccdir/  $path:q )
% make clean
% make
```

p.s. If it is by explicit name, you may be able to override it on the command line.  Something like:   **make all GCC=~/mytmpgccdir/gcc**

p.p.s If you do use LD_PRELOAD, you might want a script like this to setenv LD_PRELOAD before running your program.  Otherwise it's easy to wind up LD_PRELOAD'ing on every command like /bin/ls, make, g++, etc.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a shot!

Answer (score 2):

First, check the qmake documentation. There is an easy way to specify (in a .pro file) that a certain library should always be linked in.

Also, since you are just experimenting, simply use LD_PRELOAD - no recompilation necessary:

`LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/foo/libtcmalloc.so" ./your_program`

You do not have to have linked "your_program" against google's tcmalloc library.