# C/C++ using tcmalloc

Tags: c++, c, malloc, tcmalloc

I've been trying to compile my application using tcmalloc. Therefore I append, as recommended in the usage instructions, `-ltcmalloc` to my compiler flags. After rerunning my application I could not see any performance differences.

How can I check if the calls to malloc have been replaced like the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553435/tcmalloc-how-can-i-get-my-malloc-calls-overridden-when-compiling-statically) mentions. I had a look at the compiled assembler code but there were still calls to malloc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to check if `heap checker` is working or not, by setting env `HEAPCHECK`, e.g. `HEAPCHECK=normal`

See https://gperftools.googlecode.com/git/doc/heap_checker.html for details

Comment: And if this results in `WARNING: Perftools heap leak checker is active -- Performance may suffer` everything works as expected?

Comment: Yes, it means tcmalloc is being used.